# Why is my inline css filter in my template giving an unknown filter error when I try to email myself a newsletter issue?

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig

I am a Drupal developer and within my Drupal website, I have created a Newsletter issue called test1 newsletter.
[Newsletter content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG9h4.png)

I am using Twig as my template engine and I have applied the Twig file simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig to my test1 newsletter.

I need to put some inline css style in my Twig file. To do this, I followed the instructions given at https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/inline_css.html which told me that I first need to download a couple of libraries: twig/cssinliner-extra and twig/extra-bundle which I did in my terminal (code given below):

```
composer require twig/cssinliner-extra 
composer require twig/extra-bundle
```

This is what my simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig file looks like:

```
{% apply inline_css %}
<html>
<body>
<div id="email" style="width:600px;margin: auto;background:white;">
  <!-- Header -->
  <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E2FFF8" align="center" style="color: black;">
      <h1 style="font-size: 52px; margin:0 0 20px 0; font-family:Avenir;"> {{ node.getTitle }}</h1>
    </tr>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{% endapply %}
```

When I go to my Drupal site to email myself the test1 newsletter (under the heading "Test email address")[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vXgx.png)

I get an Unknown "inline_css" filter error. This is very weird behavior because I did successfully install the libraries to my Twig directory (from the composer require code given above).

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "inline_css" filter. in Twig\ExpressionParser->getFilterNodeClass()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted on the [inline_css page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/inline_css.html), it is not loaded by default.
Luckily for you it seems someone has already made a [module called twig_inline_css](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_inline_css) that seems to do exactly what you want.
Install the module with composer and you should be good to go. Or just copy the [small amount of code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_inline_css) into your own custom module.

Comment: This module is not covered by Drupal's security advisory policy. Furthermore, it is a dev release which is not recommended. I doubt my manager would approve the installation of this module. Is there any other option I can take?

Comment: The whole module is basically 5 lines of yml. All it does in include the twig filter you want so drupal can use it. You either include the filter the way this module has done it or you don't use the filter at all. There is no PHP in the module to even be covered by the security policy. Did you look at [the source](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_inline_css)? I mentioned that you could copy the code into your own module because I anticipated that you would point out that it is still a dev release.

Comment: So, I installed this module with composer. Clearing the cache now no longer gives an "Unknown inline_css filter" error. Now, the problem is that the css attributes I specified in the simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig file seem to get ignored when I email the newsletter to myself. Would you happen to know why this is the case even though I have an inline_css filter now?

Comment: Is the css in the source of the email? Also, lookig at it now, I am not sure why you even needed the inline_css filter, as the template code you posted already has the css inline.

Comment: As you have no opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73949811/why-is-my-inline-css-in-my-twig-template-getting-ignored-when-i-apply-it-to-a-ne) for this css issue, please mark this answer as accepted if it did actually fix the original "unknown filter" error.