# Why is my inline css in my twig template getting ignored when I apply it to a newsletter issue and then email that newsletter to myself in Drupal?

Tags: html, css, email, drupal, twig

Within my Drupal website, I have created a Newsletter issue called test1 newsletter.
[Newsletter content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG9h4.png)

I am using Twig as my template engine and I have applied the Twig file simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig to my test1 newsletter.

I need to put some inline css style in my Twig file.

This is what my simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig file looks like:

```
{% apply inline_css %}
<html>
<body>
<div id="email" style="width:600px;margin: auto;background:white;">
  <!-- Header -->
  <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E2FFF8" align="center" style="color: black;">
      <h1 style="font-size: 52px; margin:0 0 20px 0; font-family:Avenir;"> {{ node.getTitle }}</h1>
    </tr>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{% endapply %}
```

When I go to my Drupal site to email myself the test1 newsletter (under the heading "Test email address")[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vXgx.png)

I do receive the email but it seems to ignore all of the css styling I have used (and the h1 tag). [image: What the email looks like]

This is what the email should look like:
[image]

I followed the instructions given at [Why is my inline css filter in my template giving an unknown filter error when I try to email myself a newsletter issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911754/why-is-my-inline-css-filter-in-my-template-giving-an-unknown-filter-error-when-i) to set up the inline css filter but for some odd reason, the css styling seems to get ignored.